# Format with leading plus in R

Tags: r, format

Hi I'd like to format a number with a leading plus in R, is that possible?

In this particular case, I needed it because I wanted to turn a lm result into a formula.

e.g.

```
res <- lm(...)
coeff <- summary(res)$coef[-1, 1]
paste(format(summary(res)$coef[1, 1],scientific=F,digits=3),paste(format(coeff,scientific=F,digits=3,trim=T),names(coeff),sep="*",collapse=""),sep="")
```

Currently return something like

```
0.0345-0.0001189*A0.0000228*B0.0000276*C0.0000264*D-0.0000872*E-0.0000309*F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `sprintf`, e.g.,

```
sprintf("%+.2f", c(0.5, -3.8))
#[1] "+0.50" "-3.80"
```

Read `help("sprintf")` to learn more about formating options.

Answer (score 0):

If have fixed this with

```
myformat <- function(x,...) paste(ifelse(x>=0,"+",""),format(x,...),sep="")
```

But is there an inbuilt specifier?